# Angularfire generate new unique ID for non-email object

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I'm making a web app using angularfire. I have a url for users at 'url.firebaseio.com/users'. I want to make another url to store chat-room type things at 'url.firebaseio.com/rooms'. When I create a new user using the $createUser() method, it stores the user's information under a unique ID created by $createUser() in the '/users' url. I want to do this with the new '/rooms' url, but I can't find a way to generate unique IDs in the same way without $createUser(). I can't use $createUser() because it requires an email address argument, and I just want to take in a name for the room and a password, all in an object under the unique ID for the room.

I can't think of any code to provide, so here's what a user looks like:

```
users: {
   uniqueUserId: {
      email: email@email.com,
      name: name
   }
}
```

And here's what I'd like a 'room' to look like:

```
rooms: {
    uniqueRoomId: {
        roomName: something
    }
}
```

Is there a built-in way to do this? If not would it be best to generate IDs on my own?

Comment: Something like `new Firebase('https://url.firebaseio.com/').push({ roomName: 'something', password: 'BatteryHorseStaple' })`. Please read: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html

Comment: I guess I totally skipped over that in the docs. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In AngularFire, when working with collections in $firebaseArray, the $add method will handle this automagically.